# X509Certificate2 failing in Azure Webjobs calling Google API

Tags: azure, google-bigquery, azure-webjobs

I have a console app that is scheduled using Azure WebJobs. The execution always fails when attempting to read the private key of p12 certificate. Interestingly enough I can't catch the exception, I've had to use good old `Console.WriteLine` to debug.

Here is my snippet of code:

```csharp
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(data, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
 new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
 {
     Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery }
 }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

Other posts have mention that the flags should be `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` but unfortunately that causes an error in the Google API. It requires the `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` flag to be set.

Can anyone confirm that `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` is usable on Azure Websites and WebJobs?

Comment: You may find this thread helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330863/windows-azure-management-libraries-certification-error-on-web-job.

Comment: Yup, I saw that thread and blog post. The solution requires to set the `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` which is incompatible with the Google API SDK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` is not usable in IIS. I've tried it with Azure Webjobs, Azure Websites and IIS on my own virtual machine. It works in a development environment when using IISExpress because the process is running in the  user's context.

So for it work in an IIS context (including Webjobs), it has to be set to `MachineKeySet` but the Google API will fail since it needs the private key.

The solution to my problem was actually pretty simple, create a console app that creates the `X509Certificate2` object with `Exportable` flag set and then call 
`ToXmlString()`. Here is the snippet:

`var certificate = new X509Certificate2(data, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var xml = certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);`

I then save the XML and use that XML to create an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` like this:

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(xmlKey);
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
 {
  Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery },
  Key = rsa
 });
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: I love you smart people that figures this stuff out. I had nothing to go on :) Thanks!

Comment: You reference `data` when creating the X509Certificate2 object, are you pulling this out of the provided .p12 key somehow?

Comment: `data` refers to a byte array of the p12 certificate you get from Google Cloud project for OAuth credentials. Take a look at doc here: [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-server](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-server)

Comment: Good Job! Works for me as well :)

Comment: This is amazing, but see answer by jmcnly which is much easier and solves this particular problem for Azure WebJobs etc

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked in an Azure setting. However I also found one for my needs that was much simpler. Simply add additional Flags so everyone is happy...

```
 var certificate = new X509Certificate2(data,"notasecret",
                       X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | 
                       X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | 
                       X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959418/site-in-azure-websites-fails-processing-of-x509certificate2)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This should actually be a comment, not an answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, that is the answer. Now works perfectly! well done.

Comment: Agreed, other solution is genius but this does the trick and is much less work, this should be the accepted answer