# Send apple push notification from azure

Tags: c#, azure, apple-push-notifications

i am trying send push notification from azure, when i send from my local server its working fine, but when i upload my web app to azure its not working (`502 bad gateway error`). so my code is here :

```
hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";
PORT = 2195;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)), password);
X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

client = new TcpClient(hostname, PORT);
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);

writer.Write((byte)0);
writer.Write((byte)0);
writer.Write((byte)32);

writer.Write(HexString2Bytes(ReciverDeviceToken.ToUpper()));
JObject payloadData = new JObject();
JObject aps = new JObject();

aps.Add("alert", Title);
aps.Add("badge", "1");
aps.Add("sound", "sound.caf");
payloadData.Add("aps", aps);

foreach (var m in Messages)
{
    payloadData.Add(m.Key, m.Value);
}

string payloadDataToString = payloadData.ToString();

writer.Write((byte)0);
writer.Write((byte)payloadDataToString.Length);

byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payloadDataToString);

writer.Write(b1);
writer.Flush();

byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();

sslStream.Write(array);
sslStream.Flush();
client.Close();
```

i have googled, but there is no result. is there any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxFile, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

for more details please see this link

[Windows Azure Management Libraries Certification Error on Web Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330863/windows-azure-management-libraries-certification-error-on-web-jobs)